# Microsoft Graph - Get latest message content only

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a Logic App that watches a mail box and creates service tickets based on the content of those emails. They can create tickets this way or reply to them to update the ticket. The issue is with the reply. As I'm sure you know, in an email chain, the latest message has a copy of all the previous messages in the chain. Adding all this content on the comment of a ticket results in a bunch of duplication/visual clutter. So the question:

Is there a way to get only the most recent reply's text/content from a message? I was digging around the Microsoft Graph API but haven't had much luck identifying how to get this. In lieu of being able to do it via api I was going to just look for copied text in the message html and ignore it, but that seems like the way we'd do it if it was 1990.

Anyway, any help in this regard is much appreciated. Ideally it'd be done with Microsoft Graph because we're a mostly Microsoft stack here but any method is valid.

Thanks,

~Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out we ended up doing it with Microsoft Graph as expected. You have to jump through a few hoops (registering your application in Azure, getting a bearer token and such) but the end result is you can call:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}?$select=uniqueBody

This will return your message's unique body.

[image: Ended up doing this to get a fresh token every time]

To save you some time the request for the bearer token looks like this (you can use anything for the form-data boundary):

[image: Bearer Token Request]

And then you add the token to the uniqueBody Request like this:

[image: Message unique body request]

Please consult the Microsoft documentation for how to get these fields for your application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user